# Installed truffle globally using npm but still cannot access it

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle, ganache

I have installed nodejs and then tried running the following command to install truffle suit and ganache as follows:
npm install -g truffle
npm install -g ganache
It got installed as follows:
[Installing truffle and ganache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3PXf.png)
I also checked whether its present in the directories or not by running the command:
npm list -g

Yet when I run the command:
truffle -v
ganache -v
I get the error:
[Error after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiZNW.png)

The package although it was installed globally, I couldn't access the package. I do have VS CODE and python 3.11 installed. Any suggestions to how can I use it globally?
I did try the following:

1. running npm config edit
   changing the prefix to 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm'
   adding that path to the system path variable
   reinstalling the package with -g.
2. explicitly set the path by
   npm config set prefix c:/Users//AppData/Roaming/npm
3. Change the permission of node global package without tampering with default file permission by
   rather changing the directory itself along creating a new profile.
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   npm config set prefix `~/.npm-global`
   set PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   source ~/.profile
   npm install -g <npm_packages>

But none of them worked